# Ошибка шины (стек памяти сброшен на диск)51 format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument /fprintf(flog,"%s:- out.txt\n",ctime(&clock),ch);

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<ctype.h>


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
time_t clock;
int i,j,kol_vo, N,M;
char ch[300];
FILE *fin, *flog, *fout;
puts("###################################################### ################");

puts(" Отфарматировать текстовый файл. Абзацный отступ N пробелов. MAX длина строки М символов");

puts("###################################################### ################");
puts("Все действия данной программы записываются в протокол log.txt");
puts("Выходные данные находятся в файле out.txt");
puts("Текстовый файл, протокол и выходной файл находятся в домашнем каталоге");
puts("###################################################### ################");

if ((flog=fopen("log.txt","a"))==NULL)
{
puts("Ошибка открытия протокола!!!");
exit(0);
}
clock=time(NULL);
fprintf(flog,"%s:Протокол открыт успешно\n",ctime(&clock));
clock=time(NULL);
if (argc<3)
{
puts("Ошибка! Используйте ./text1 filename N M");
puts("Где filename - название входного файла");
puts("Где M-макс.длина строки N-абзацный отступ");
clock=time(NULL);
fprintf(flog,"%s:Ошибка открытия входного файла\n",ctime(&clock));
clock=time(NULL);
fprintf(flog,"%s:Работа завершена\n",ctime(&clock));
fclose(flog);
puts("Нажмите Enter!");
getchar();
exit(0);
N=atoi(argv[2]);
M=atoi(argv[3]);
}

if(N<3 || N>10) N=8;
if(M<30 || M>100) M=60;
fprintf(flog,"%s:Неверно введены данные\n");

if ((fin=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
{

clock=time(NULL);
fprintf(flog,"%s:Ошибка открытия входного файла %s\n",ctime(&clock),argv[1]);
fclose(flog);
puts("Ошибка открытия входного файла");
exit(0);
}
else
{
clock=time(NULL);
fprintf(flog,"%s:Входной файл %s открыт успешно\n",ctime(&clock),argv[1]);
}
if ((fout=fopen("out.txt","w"))==NULL)
{
clock=time(NULL);
fprintf(flog,"%s:Ошибка открытия выходного файла\n",ctime(&clock));
puts("Ошибка открытия выходного файла");
exit(0);
}
else
{
clock=time(NULL);
fprintf(flog,"%s:Выходной файл открыт успешно\n",ctime(&clock));
}
while (!feof(fin))
{
fgets(ch,298,fin);
clock=time(NULL);
kol_vo=strlen(ch);j=0;
if(strncmp(ch," ",3)==0){j=N;
for(i=1;i<=N-3;i++)
fprintf(fout," ");}


for(i=j;i<kol_vo;i++)
{fprintf(fout,"%c",ch[i]);if(((i%M)==0)&&i!=0)fprintf(fout,"\n");}




}



fprintf(flog,"%s:- out.txt\n",ctime(&clock),ch);
fclose(fin);
clock=time(NULL);
fprintf(flog,"%s:Входной файл закрыт\n",ctime(&clock));
fclose(fout);
clock=time(NULL);
fprintf(flog,"%s:Выходной файл закрыт\n",ctime(&clock));
clock=time(NULL);
fprintf(flog,"%s:Работа завершена\n",ctime(&clock));
fclose(flog);
puts("Нажмите Enter!");
getchar();
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: по идее программа должна отформатировать исходный файл например задаётся 5 абзацев и 20 символов она должна через каждый 20 символов сделать абзац 5 раз

Comment: отформатировать текстовый файл. Абзацный отступ N пробелов. с Max длина строки M символов

Comment: при компиляции читайте предупреждения и исправьте. Потом проверьте ещё раз. Ошибки здесь : `fprintf(flog,"%s:Неверно введены данные\n");` *(нет аргументов)* и здесь `fprintf(flog,"%s:- out.txt\n",ctime(&clock),ch);` *(много аргументов)*

Comment: Если не знаете как, почитайте инструкции про функцию `printf`.